# Best Way to reliably work on Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, css, web, browser, responsive-design

I am a fairly new web developer and I just want to gather some intel on how You guys make a web app responsive.
I have been using the built in tool in Chrome ever since I started, but it doesn't seem to be as accurate as I would love.

Pretty much every time I deploy an app, which looked amazing in the Chrome Tool, I find that some components are jacked and they don't look like they are supposed to, so I want to know if there is a better way of working on responsive design out there that is more accurate.

What do you guys use or how do you tackle the inaccuracies in Chrome Dev Tools?

Thanks in advance and have a great day! :)

Comment: If I understood correctly you are using dev tools to test it after the deployment?

Comment: No. I use it while I'm developing and everything looks brilliant. But when I deploy it and check it out on an actual mobile device, some features look off, which makes it harder to adjust and fix, since the Chrome Dev Tools show me inaccurate results.

Comment: Like I literally have to make a small change, redeploy, check it out, fix again .. and repeat the process until everything is where I want it to be and how I want it to be, which makes using Chrome Dev Tools a bit confusing and demoralizing.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that works for me is to use services like `browserstack` where you can test it on a real devices while you are developing it.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you! :)